# Why do I have two collations in mysqldump, under stored procs?

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

When I run mysqldump --routines  I'm seeing multiple collations for my stored procs. Neither my DB nor columns use utf8mb (I understand the benefits of utf8mb over utf8 but let's leave it for now).

```
/*!50003 SET sql_mode              = @saved_sql_mode */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_client  = @saved_cs_client */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_results = @saved_cs_results */ ;
/*!50003 SET collation_connection  = @saved_col_connection */ ;
ALTER DATABASE `pushcoin` CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;
/*!50003 DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_cron_get_money_pool_balance` */;
ALTER DATABASE `pushcoin` CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci ;
/*!50003 SET @saved_cs_client      = @@character_set_client */ ;
/*!50003 SET @saved_cs_results     = @@character_set_results */ ;
/*!50003 SET @saved_col_connection = @@collation_connection */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_client  = utf8 */ ;
/*!50003 SET character_set_results = utf8 */ ;
/*!50003 SET collation_connection  = utf8_general_ci */ ;
/*!50003 SET @saved_sql_mode       = @@sql_mode */ ;
/*!50003 SET sql_mode              = 'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION' */ ;
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER=`admin`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_name...`
```

The database seems all utf8...

```
MySQL> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE  'char%';
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                                         |
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                                          |
| character_set_connection | utf8                                          |
| character_set_database   | utf8                                          |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                                        |
| character_set_results    | utf8                                          |
| character_set_server     | utf8                                          |
| character_set_system     | utf8                                          |
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MySQL> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE  'coll%';
+----------------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name        | Value           |
+----------------------+-----------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_database   | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_server     | utf8_general_ci |
+----------------------+-----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reason for multiplicity of character/collation settings in MySQL?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/167777/reason-for-multiplicity-of-character-collation-settings-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

(Some of this answer is 'guesses'.)

Each database has a *default* charset and collation.  That is used only for providing the charset and/or collation for a `CREATE TABLE` when you don't explicitly provide it for the table.  (And perhaps for Stored Routines.)

Why are there two `ALTERs` in that dump?  I don't know.  Perhaps it would make sense if there were a `CREATE PROCEDURE` between them.

My point is that your question is about something that is essentially irrelevant.

The `SHOW VARIABLES` output does not say "The database seems all utf8".  It does say that certain defaults are `utf8` and that connections will assume the *client* is using utf8 unless otherwise specified.